# Abnormal output using character data type

Tags: c

I wrote a code for practice in C in Turbo c 3.1. My objective was to get the character output. My code is as follows:

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<conio.h>

    void main(){

       char a[10],b;
       int i;

       clrscr();

       for(i=0;i<10;i++)
          a[i]='$';

       for(i=0;i<10;i++){
          b=getchar();
          a[i]=b;
       }

           for(i=0;i<10;i++)
      printf("%c",a[i]);

       getch();
   }
```

Here, I had to get 10 characters with what I had input but after execution I got only 5 characters. I couldn't get the problem lying here. 
Can you please help me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're probably not counting '\n' as a character.

Comment: so how to make the correction, den?

Comment: Considering that Turbo C 3.1 is more than 20 years old, could *that* be the problem? In the usual car analogy it's a Ford model T.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> so how to make the correction, den?

How about:

```
int ch;

while (i < 10 && (ch = getchar()) != EOF)
    if (ch != '\n')
        a[i++] = ch;
```

Answer (score 3):

When you do getchar() , it reads a character.

Therefore when you type something like
a, and then enter,
what you type is actually 2 characters which are`a` and `'\n'`.
Therefore, you get only 5 characters and 5 '\n' in your output.

Try this

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main(){

   char a[10],b;
   int i;

   clrscr();

   for(i=0;i<10;i++)
      a[i]='$';

   for(i=0;i<10;i++){
      b=getchar();
      if(b=='\n'){i--;continue;}
      a[i]=b;
   }

   for(i=0;i<10;i++)
   printf("%c",a[i]);

   getch();
}
```

Comment: @user2015915 Okay, I may sound mean, but I can't let slide. Please use proper grammar and spelling when you post on SO. It's hard to take someone seriously when every sentence they write looks like LOLSpeech.

Comment: @aakash: thnx for ur nice help

Comment: @AakashAnuj, I was referring to the OP. Sorry I latched onto your answer, but my need was too great :)

Answer (score 2):

You could do an easy scanf to solve your problem

```
scanf("%c",&a[i]);
```

But still, to understand what getchar() does,  Every time you call it, it reads the next character of input and returns it to you irrespective of the character. In your case, you type a `\n` character after you input the number.So it stores first of your numbers with `\n` after each of them.

You could do this check if you are addicted to `getchar()`

```
      if(c=getchar()) == '\n')
         c=getchar();
```

Comment: thnx frnd for ur kind help

Answer (score 1):

Simpler solution maybe to use:

`scanf("%c",&a[i]);`

instead of :

`b = getchar();`
`a[i] = b;`

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you can use `getch()` or `getche()` instead of `getchar()` to read a character.